# Vb script string comparison error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vbscript, asp-classic

I have tried all but its not working

I am getting a colum value form Data base as

```
substatus=rsprefobj("isnotificationactive");
```

after doing

```
Response.write substatus
```

It gives me --> n

and when i do

```
intcomaprestringval=StrComp(substatus,"n",vbTextCompare)
     Response.write intcomaprestringval
```

It(intcomaprestringval) gives me --> 1 even though they are same

I want to take some decision based on database value if its "n" or "y"

```
If intcomaprestringval = 0  Then
some

Else

some 
End If
```

But StrComp()always returns 1 in my case whether database value is "n" or "y" :(

Comment: Maybe `substatus` starts with a whitespace character

Comment: Thanks @Entbark...u saved my time.. :)
I used 

Dim myvalue
myvalue=Trim(substatus)
intcomaprestringval=StrComp(myvalue,"n",vbTextCompare)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Trim() as suggested by @EntBark

```
Dim myvalue
myvalue=Trim(substatus)
intcomaprestringval=StrComp(myvalue,"n",vbTextCompare)
```

Answer (score 0):

I write a compare function that will return either "OK" if 2 values are a match or "No Match" if they do not. Here it is:

```
Function Compare(str1, str2, comp)
    str = "OK"
    If StrComp(str1, str2, comp) <> 0 Then str = "No Match"
    Compare = str
End Function
```

str1 and str2 are the 2 values you wish to compare and comp is the method of comparison (0 = binary comparison and 1 = text comparison). I always use 0.

So you would use it like this:

```
If Compare(substatus, "n", 0) = "OK" Then

    ' Values match

Else

    'Values do not match

End If
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Ha seems pointless I know but I could never remember what StrComp returned for a match and what it returned for no match, so I did so I could just compare the "OK" and didn't have to look it up every time I used it

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your test:

```
intcomaprestringval=StrComp(substatus,"n",vbTextCompare)
```

Are you setting vbTextCompare to be 0 at some point earlier in your code?

Comment: no..it got resolved as it was additional space issue .I used Trim ().